# SVG path in javafx 3d viewer

Tags: svg, javafx, 3d

I am trying to load SVGPath (simple line) in JavaFx 3D viewer. I tried adding the SVGPath class object to Group and added it on scene, but it shows only in 2D. Is there a way I can change this to 3D representation. I also tried using JavaFx 3D Shapes like Box and Cylinder but not sure whether it is a correct way to do that. Following is my code.

```
Group relationGrp = new Group();
SVGPath path = new SVGPath();
path.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
path.setStrokeWidth(10);
path.setContent("M -15 -60 L -15 15 L 60 15z");
svg3dModelGrp.getChildren().add(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `SVGPath` only allows **2D drawing**, why ? Because you just have to introduce (positionX, positionY, and some curve details...) in each action  and Logically **a line has no depth**:

```
//MoveTo (from positionX and positionY) / LineTo (to positionX and positionY)
Mx y , Lx y ...
```

You can play with the path to create depth effects by creating many shapes one behind the other with a decremented size but I do not believe that the `SVGPath` is made for this purpose !

**Wikipedia** :

> Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is an XML-based vector image format for **two-dimensional graphics**

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes correct SVGPath is for 2D graphics. But since I wanted to show that as 3D i am trying to achive that with some solution, What I am exactly looking for is kind of thin cylinder(a pipe) that connects two boxes(Shape3D). I also tried Polyline3D Class from open source (Fxyz) and i was able to get 3D lines (with z+/z-), but i have to use mesh, in my logic i dont use MeshView class. I use only primitives. May be i should try some custom logic. Please advice.

Comment: A little bit late, but you can have a look at the [SVG3DMesh](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/SVG3DMesh.java) from the FXyz3D library.